# How do I change the font of only the highlited text?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm making a word processor, and want the user to have the ability to bold only the text you select on windows phone with the tap/hold/drag. I know how to detect what text is selected by the user with Filebox.SelectedText (filebox is the name of the textbox), but have no idea where to go from there - how do I take the text that is selected and ONLY make that selected text bolded?

Note: I am using ComponentOne's Rich Textbox control.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `RichTextBox.Selection` property.

For example:

```
private void ModifySelectedText()
{
   // Determine if text is selected in the control. 
   if (richTextBox1.SelectionLength > 0)
   {
      // Set the color of the selected text in the control.
      richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
      // Set the font of the selected text to bold and underlined.
      richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Arial",10,FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Underline);
      // Protect the selected text from modification.
      richTextBox1.SelectionProtected = true;
   }
}
```